# How to upload S3 files in KeystoneJS

Tags: node.js, express, amazon-s3, keystonejs

I have an item called style which has 2 attributes, one which has raw css text and another which has an [S3File](http://keystonejs.com/docs/database/#fieldtypes-s3file).

```
Style.add({
  ...
  css: { type: Types.Code, language: 'css' },
  cssFile: {
    type: Types.S3File,
    s3path: 'uploads/assets',
  },
  ...
});
```

I want to update the [S3File](http://keystonejs.com/docs/database/#fieldtypes-s3file) with the contents of the css text.

```
function uploadCSStoAmazon(style) {
  // Store css code in temporal file (with a md5 name)
  var rndm = crypto.randomBytes(20).toString('hex'), file_path = '/tmp/css_temp_' + rndm + '.css';

  fs.writeFile(file_path, style.css, function(err) {
    if(err) {
      return console.log(err);
    }

    console.log("The file was saved!");

    // style.cssFile = new Types.S3File();

    // TODO upload file to amazon
    style.cssFile._.uploadFile(file_path, true, function(err, fileData){
      // TODO erase css file
    });
  });

}

...

var aStyle = new Style.model({
  ...
  css: 'Some css string',
  ...
});


...

uploadCSStoAmazon(aStyle);
```

The cssFile attribute is undefined, I understand, but how could I create a new file and assign it to this attribute, and also upload the file?

Comment: How/where are you calling `uploadCSStoAmazon()`?

Comment: I just edited the question to show how i'd call the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out how, you can use the updateHandler that comes with Keystone. They're still using req.files form express 3.x though.

```js
// A express file generator

function writeToFile(fileName, txt, ext, callback) {
  var rndm = crypto.randomBytes(20).toString('hex'), file_path = '/tmp/css_temp_' + rndm + '.' + ext, the_file = {};

  fs.writeFile(file_path, txt, function(err) {
    if(err) {
      callback(null, err);
    }

    var stats = fs.statSync(file_path);
    var fileSizeInBytes = stats["size"];

    the_file.path = file_path;
    the_file.name = fileName + '.' + ext;
    the_file.type = 'text/' + ext;
    the_file.size = fileSizeInBytes;

    console.log("The file was cached!");
    callback(the_file, err);
  });
}

...

/**
 * Update Style by ID
 */
exports.update = function(req, res) {
  var data = (req.method == 'POST') ? req.body : req.query;

  Style.model.findById(data._id).exec(function(err, item) {
    
    if (err) return res.apiError('database error', err);
    if (!item) return res.apiError('not found');

    writeToFile(item.slug, data.css, 'css', function(req_file, err){

      if (err) return res.apiError('update error during file cache', err);

      req.files['cssFile_upload'] = req_file;

      item.getUpdateHandler(req).process(data, function(err) {
      
        if (err) return res.apiError('update error', err);

        res.apiResponse({
          success: true
        });

      }); // end process

    }); // end writeToFile

  });
};
```