# Uploading LocalFile in Keystone.js using UpdateHandler

Tags: javascript, node.js, image-uploading, keystonejs

How might one go about doing this? [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30517840/how-to-upload-s3-files-in-keystonejs), someone suggests using an UpdateHandler or an underscore method of the list item as in `profileImage._.uploadImage(file, update, callback)` to handle the file upload, but they use an `S3 File` instead of a `LocalFile`. I tried using an underscore method first but it doesn't seem to work as it does in the above question. There's a lot of scattered documentation on other sites but it all appears to be outdated (some suggest using methods of the `LocalFile` that don't exist anymore, for example) and contains many broken links.

View js (middleware) code:

```
view.on('post', { action: 'edit-profile' }, next => {       
    let updater = locals.user.getUpdateHandler(req, res, {
        errorMessage: 'There was an error editing your profile:'
    });

    updater.process(req.body, {
        flashErrors: true,
        logErrors: true,
        fields: 'profileImage, email, name, password'
    }, err => {
        if (err) {
            locals.validationErrors = err.errors;
            next();
        } else {
            req.flash('success', 'Profile updated');
            res.redirect('/profile');
        }
    });
});
```

Jade code:

```
mixin edit-profile()
form(method='post', enctype='multipart/form-data', autocomplete='off', novalidate).form-horizontal.create-form.profile-form
    input(type='hidden', name='action', value='edit-profile')

    .row: .col-sm-8.col-sm-offset-2

        h2 Edit Profile

        .form-group
            +user-picture(locals.user)
            label(for="profileImage") Change profile picture
            input(type='file', id='profileImage' name='profileImage')
        .form-group
            label(for="email") Email
            input(type='email', value=locals.user.email, size="40", id='email', name='email', placeholder='email').input.input-xl.input-faded
        .form-group
            label(for="email") Name
            input(type='text', value=locals.user.name.first, name='name.first', placeholder='First name').input.input-xl.input-faded
            input(type='text', value=locals.user.name.last, name='name.last', placeholder='Last name').input.input-xl.input-faded
        .form-group
            label(for="password") Change password
            input(type='password', id="password", name='password', placeholder='password').input.input-xl.input-faded
            input(type='password', name='password_confirm', placeholder='password').input.input-xl.input-faded
        .form-group
            button(type='submit', data-loading-text="Changing...").btn.btn-lg.btn-primary.btn-block Update profile
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out the issue is that Keystone.js is very picky about what the input field is named when it comes to LocalFile uploads. It isn't documented *anywhere* on Keystone's website (in fact, nothing about UpdateHandler is it seems), but you need to put `_upload` after the name.

So, the Jade code should look like this (notice the difference in the first `.form-group`):

```
mixin edit-profile()
form(method='post', enctype='multipart/form-data', autocomplete='off', novalidate).form-horizontal.create-form.profile-form
input(type='hidden', name='action', value='edit-profile')

.row: .col-sm-8.col-sm-offset-2

    h2 Edit Profile

    .form-group
        +user-picture(locals.user)
        label(for="profileImage_upload") Change profile picture
        input(type='file', id='profileImage_upload' name='profileImage_upload')
    .form-group
        label(for="email") Email
        input(type='email', value=locals.user.email, size="40", id='email', name='email', placeholder='email').input.input-xl.input-faded
    .form-group
        label(for="email") Name
        input(type='text', value=locals.user.name.first, name='name.first', placeholder='First name').input.input-xl.input-faded
        input(type='text', value=locals.user.name.last, name='name.last', placeholder='Last name').input.input-xl.input-faded
    .form-group
        label(for="password") Change password
        input(type='password', id="password", name='password', placeholder='password').input.input-xl.input-faded
        input(type='password', name='password_confirm', placeholder='password').input.input-xl.input-faded
    .form-group
        button(type='submit', data-loading-text="Changing...").btn.btn-lg.btn-primary.btn-block Update profile
```

If you're using standard HTML, it's no different really. Just set the id and name of the input to be `fieldnamehere_upload` (in my case, the LocalFile's field name is `profileImage`). The updater code is accurate as is (be careful, the order of the `fields` in the argument to `updater.process` should be the same as the order of the input fields in your form).

I wouldn't recommend using the underscore method the list has. It seems harder than using the UpdateHandler as shown here.